# how to get list of all models and libraries used by a controller in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, controllers

i want to get the information of all models used by a controller and which libraries used by which function for example

i have a controller functions test i want to check which classes ,libraries,models and views associated by this controller call.

And list of all available functions in codeigniter framework

Answer (score 0):

`var_dump(get_instance());`
or
`var_dump($this);`
and you'll get Object ( Controller_name ) info.